# How do I setup Windows Server 2008 as NAT with one NIC?

Tags: windows-server-2008, nat

How would I setup Windows Server 2008 as NAT router with only one nic? I only have access to a server with one nic and I can't add a nic to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - you can't. In order to route something, there needs to be connections to two different networks.

Long answer, maybe you could if the one nic was assigned ip addresses on two vlans on the same switch and routed between them. I have not tried this, and I am not sure it would work. It would be much easier to add another nic. I am thinking it is a hosted solution you are working with, and if you cannot add a nic, you probably do not have access to the switch to implement the vlans either.

Answer (score 5):

I've wrote simple 11 steps to setup VPN + NAT with single NIC here : https://plus.google.com/u/0/108197739169919071168/posts/bnDbKbrFPq6

---

here is steps :

```
How to setup VPN+NAT on your Windows Server with Single NIC :
1- Add RRAS Role in server manager.
2- Enable Routing & Remote Access
3- Choose "Custom" because you have only one NIC.
4- Choose VPN + NAT + Dialin
5- Press next , then "start service"
6- In management console, right click on "NAT" and select " add interface"
7- Select your only NIC
8 - Select "public interface ..." and "Enable NAT"
9- Right click on "server-name" in console and choose properties
10 - choose IPv4 tab and select "Static address pool"
11 - Add an IP range different from your client IP range
```

( I selected 192.168.100.x when my client ip is 192.168.1.x )

VPN Server+NAT is now must work for you

---

I did it myself and I'm posting this post while I'm connected to that server!